# Largest molecule that isn't polymer?

Tags: molecules

What is the largest molecule (synthetic or natural) that isn't a polymer -- let's say, bigger than 3000 dalton?

Comment: Do covalent solids count? In that case, imagine the largest possible diamond, quartz crystal, etc.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE. I am worried that this question will not have a definitive answer. What I mean is that everyone who answers will provide the largest molecule they can think of. Then someone will discover a bigger molecule and invalidate all the existing answers.

Comment: I wouldn't expect a definitive answer, since the notions involved are not really well-defined. That being said, maitotoxin sounds like a good example.

Comment: Are biomolecules such as proteins or DNA considered to be polymers?

Comment: @aventurin - yes.

Answer (score 1):

An old German book about chemical records (Quadbeck-Seeger, H.-J., Ed. *Chemie Rekorde;* Wiley-VCH: Weinheim, 1997) gives the [Cullinan Diamond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cullinan_Diamond) as the largest found natural molecule and a synthetic diamond of 38.4 carat as the largest made artificial molecule.